# Only show layer preview for group layers the user can access

Tags: geoserver, authentication

I'm having problems using geoserver to serve geodata to some customers without displaying their respective group layers to each other (version 2.8.2).

Both users have access to their own workspace and it works well. The problem is that they can see a list of all group layers on the *Layer Preview* page. Even users that are not logged in at all can see the list. Can I prevent this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the layer group "mode" to "container tree", this will remove it from the layer preview. I discovered this from reading through https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html.